# prestashop: where to override css file

Tags: prestashop

I want to override the file 
/modules/moduleName/views/css/moduleName.css

I tried to put my file in

- /themes/myTheme/modules/moduleName/views/css/moduleName.css

or in

- /themes/myTheme/css/modules/moduleName/moduleName.css

but it did not work.

where is the correct override folder for such file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think correct way will be

- /themes/myTheme/css/modules/moduleName/views/css/moduleName.css

The only question, why it so deep, why not css folder inside module? 
Like this
/themes/myTheme/modules/moduleName/css/moduleName.css
And override 
/themes/myTheme/css/modules/moduleName/css/moduleName.css

Comment: I think PrestaShop doesn't want to plow to much through folders in order to get all the necessary css/js files together. It's the only thing I can come up with. But yes, it is very inconvenient for Presta-developers..